# iOS Geofencing; will this be more accurate than what I have now?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I am by no means an iOS developer, and am just hacking something basic together for myself. Sorry if this is too beginner of a question.

I'm trying to collect my own location data from my phone to my own back-end service. Looking around, I found a sample project to collect location info: https://github.com/chriseidhof/PostGPS/

From the looks of things, this project uses significant location update, so even though I changed my desired accuracy to 100 meters, the app will still only provide update when enough cell towers have changed.

Instead, I'm thinking of using geofencing (CLCircularRegion) by creating grids of 3x3 geofences with 500 meter radius (with maybe a 50 meter overlap between each region), and each time I exit the central region, a new set of 3x3 geofences gets generated.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this (the deleting and re-fencing part) a correct use of geofencing on iOS?
2. Is this going to be more accurate than what I currently have?
3. Will this significantly negatively affect my battery life?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using geofencing is that you can't monitor more than 20 regions at a time(OS limitation). It's better to use significant location changes. It is triggered while you're in foreground or background and the location is updated if the cell tower has changed or you have opened the app while the app was not in memory. But this method will be triggered only in the intervals of 15 mins. So even if the cell tower changes rapidly, this method will be invoked only once in 15 mins.

So if you want to update the location in background keeping in mind the battery usage as well, use significant location api.

Comment: Would it be possible to delete the existing 3x3 and re-create new 3x3 fences in the background to work around the 20 regions limit?

Comment: As far as I know, if the other apps require monitoring other regions in their app. The OS might start cleaning up the monitored regions and there is a chance that the region you're monitoring in your app might get removed. So it's better to use significant location api.